# javascript canvas - generating a dynamic grid of squares on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am working on a simple program in JS that creates a grid of squares on a canvas of any size. I am able to generate half the grid but for some reason my other half does not appear on the screen.

could anyone see a potentially flaw in my logic?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(x, 0, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);


    while (x < canvas.width / 2) {
      var y = 0;
      while (y < canvas.height) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#77f442";
        ctx.fillRect(x + 30, y + 10, 20, 20);
        ctx.stroke();
        y = y + 50;
      }
      x = x + 50;
    }

    //var x = canvas.width / 2;

    while ((x >= (canvas.width / 2)) && (x < canvas.width)) {
      var y = 0;
      while ((y >= (canvas.height)) && (y < canvas.height)) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#77f442";
        ctx.fillRect(x + 10, y + 10, 20, 20);
        ctx.stroke();
        y = y + 50;
      }
      x = x + 50;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: half a grid filled with squares]

Comment: You divide the width by two everywhere

Comment: You're dividing width by 2 in a lot of places, which would seem to be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had a logic error where I was checking for `(y >= (canvas.height)`

the fix was to use `<` instead of `>=`

correct code:

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(x, 0, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);

    while (x < canvas.width) {
      if (x < canvas.width / 2) {
        var y = 0;
        while (y < canvas.height) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.fillStyle = "#77f442";
          ctx.fillRect(x + 30, y + 10, 20, 20);
          ctx.stroke();
          y = y + 50;
        }
        x = x + 50;
      }
      else if (x == canvas.width / 2)
      {
        while ((x >= (canvas.width / 2)) && (x < canvas.width)) {
          var y = 0;
          while ((y <= (canvas.height))) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#77f442";
            ctx.fillRect(x , y + 10, 20, 20);
            ctx.stroke();
            y = y + 50;
          }
          x = x + 50;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```